# How to store models in a dataframe or any other data type

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a list of ML models (Random Forest, Logistic Regression, Naive Bayse, etc.)

each one of these algorithms along with its parameters is related a record in my list

here is an example of it

```
id     Type           RecodsNo       DataSetFile      Algorithm
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1      Soccer Match   19488          Soccer.csv       RandomForestClassifier(max_features="sqrt", n_jobs=3)
2      Weather data   93748          Weather.csv      LogisticRegression(C=0.1, solver="liblinear")
3      School data    88399          School.csv       RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000)
4      Bank CC        37548          Bank.csv         LogisticRegression(C=1.0, solver="liblinear")
..
..
2204   Finance data   22933          Fin.csv          LogisticRegression(C=0.4)
```

I tried to store these models as a string and then retrieve it in dynamic form but that did not work as `eval()` function does not operate this way

is there anyway I can store these models as models in a dataframe or any other data structure ?

something like this

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_features="sqrt", n_jobs=3)
df["Algorithm",1] = clf
```

so that when I need to call it I use

```
clf = df["Algorithm",1] 
clf.fit(...)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling a function of a module by using its name (a string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string)

Comment: @nw not sure how this relevant to my problem !!

Comment: What do you get if you do ```df[‘Algorithm’] = list_of_algorithms``` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a list of dictionaries:

```py
dict_classifiers = {

    "Random Forest": RandomForestClassifier(),
    "Gradient Boosting Classifier": GradientBoostingClassifier(),
    "Linear SVM": SVC(),
    "XGB": XGBRegressor(),
    "Logistic Regression": LogisticRegression(),
    "Nearest Neighbors": KNeighborsClassifier(),
    "Decision Tree": DecisionTreeClassifier(),
}


for classifier_name in dict_classifiers.keys():

    print("training: ", classifier_name)
    classifier_name.fit(...)
```

Comment: how to store that with other info.